# Cannot import name active_contour

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am studying a beginners guide on a sci-image, I successfully downloaded scikit-image via `easy_install` when I tried the code as shown on this site:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html#example-edges-plot-active-contours-py

I get an error stating that `from skimage.segmentation import active_contour` has an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name active_contour

My first solution, as what I have read on the internet is to delete the library I am using and re-installing it using `pip_install` however I still get the same result. Any advice on this thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The `active_contour_model` is only avaiable in the `development` version of `skikit-image` and will (probably) be included in the `skimage v.0.12` but until then you need to manually install the development version found on https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image.

The documentation of the `stable` version of `skimage.segmentation` is here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html

Comment: We'll have a release out within the next week or two.  Thanks for waiting!